# Is there is any Alt + F4 alternative in Chrome OS or Chrome OS Flex?

Tags: google-chrome-os, google-chrome-os-flex

In windows or other Linux based distributions, we can press Alt + F4 to close any application or to shut down overall PC as shutdown menu appear by it. I know Ctrl + W shortcut, but it is only work Chrome OS built in program it does not work on Linux program which I have installed like WPS Office. So is there is anyway I can close a Linux Application or shutdown Chrome OS by Keyboard?

Comment: This [article](https://www.oakcitytechnology.com/how-to/pro-tip-thursday-3-top-4-chromebook-hotkeys-you-didnt-know-you-had/) says : "Search + Alt + #4". Does it make sense?

Comment: The Search + Alt + 4 shortcut does not work.